# select data with inner joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables I want to get information from.

Tables

**tblStaff**

id | name

**tblWork**

userid | week

**tblOff**

userid | week

For example, if Michael has a value or multiple values in the `week` colum of either `tblWork` or `tblOff` then I want those values returned.

**UPDATE**

This one works almost as I want. Except, If the `tblOff` and `tblWork` looks like this:

Michael = userid 1

Dan = userid 2

tblWork

userid, week

1    |  2014 v47

1    |  2014 v50

2    |  2014 v48

tblOff

userid, week

1    | 2014 v48

1    | 2014 v49

2    | 2014 v52

Then I only get the first result in both tables on Michael, I do not get both `week` values.

```
SELECT tblStaff.name as name, tblWork.week as work_week, tblOff.week as off_week
                        FROM tblStaff
                        LEFT JOIN tblWork
                        ON tblStaff.id = tblWork.userid
                        LEFT JOIN tblOff
                        ON tblStaff.id = tblOff.userid
                        GROUP BY tblStaff.name
```

**SLOVED**

This is what I did. After I use explode() to separate the values to check them to the current year+week

```
SELECT tblStaff.name as name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblWork.week) as work_week, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblOff.week) as off_week
                        FROM tblStaff
                        LEFT JOIN tblWork
                            ON tblStaff.id = tblWork.userid
                        LEFT JOIN tblOff 
                            ON tblStaff.id = tblOff.userid
                        GROUP BY tblStaff.name
                        ORDER BY tblStaff.name ASC
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of what you want to see and what your tables look like?

Comment: I updated the question. As it is now, it dose not list anything. No error, so i must be asking the wrong question.

Comment: you have two options I can think of off the top of my head for the query.  You can group concat, which will group all entries in a certain column, separated by something you chose (for example, a block of HTML code if you want) that returns as one column for a specific grouping value (e.g. name to get all of one name's values).  Or you can pivot the query which is more complicated.

Comment: I tried GROUP_CONCAT(DISTNICT tblStaff.name) as name and no GROUP BY. I get an answer now, all the names in a row, then only one line of year+week, I want the line of year+week after each name

Comment: the column in group_concat is what gets concatenated, so you would want group_concat(week)   and then group by name at the end.

Comment: Can you please give some examples of the values in your `tblWork.week` column?  In your php code, where is `$theweek` defined?

Comment: tblWork.week could be 2014 v47 or any other year+week depending on when they are planed into a certain job. I saw the variable before, and changed it in my code, forgot to change it here, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `tblWork.week` column contains values like `2014 v47` then the result of

```
SELECT tblStaff.name as name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblWork.week ORDER BY tblWork.week) as work_week
etc
```

will be something like this.

```
name       work_week
Michael    2014 v47,2014 v48,2014 v50,2014 v51
George     2014 v49,2014 v50,2014 v51
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` creates a string with comma-separated values in it.

If you want

```
name       work_week
Michael    2014 v47 | 2014 v48 | 2014 v50 | 2014 v51
```

you'll need

```
SELECT tblStaff.name as name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tblWork.week ORDER BY tblWork.week SEPARATOR ' | ') as work_week
```

Your php program doesn't seem to be expecting the kind of text string `GROUP_CONCAT()` generates.

To get one row per person name with columns for work weeks and off weeks, you're going to need a nested query like this.

```
SELECT a.name, b.weeks as work_week, c.weeks as off_week
  FROM tblStaff a
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT userid, 
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT week
                                  ORDER BY week 
                                  SEPARATOR ' | ') as weeks
                FROM tblWork
               GROUP BY userid               
            ) b ON a.id = b.userid
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT userid, 
                     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT week
                                  ORDER BY week 
                                  SEPARATOR ' | ') as weeks
                FROM tblOff
               GROUP BY userid               
            ) c ON a.id = c.userid
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle showing this.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f63e0/1/0

You need to do the `GROUP BY` operations separately on `tblWork` and `tblOff`. If you join them and then do the `GROUP BY`, you'll get a combinatorial explosion which is no good.

Comment: Thank you Ollie for the help! I tried that but I could not get it to work, then I tried to rewrite it and I almost got it right, but not all the way there. I updated the question with my attempt.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I should know better than to write a query as complex as that without trying it.  I've edited it. Here it is, working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f63e0/1/0

Comment: Thanks a lot Ollie!! I did not use exactly that code, since I saw your respond after I wrote another one, but you pushed me in the right direction, thanks a lot!